# Why won't my external css libraries be found in production with cssbundling-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cssbundling-rails

I have a few css libraries in my rails 7 app, like bootstrap & flatpicker. In development they both load fine, but in production only bootstrap is loading.

I get a "Failed to load resource: the server responded witha status of 404" error in reference to slimselect in the js console. When I look at resources, I can see the file in the path, but the file is empty.

In the Sources tab, I can see bootstrap in the generic css file assets/application-{long-hash}.css, where as slimselect is in assets/slim-select/dist/slimselect.min.css (but no code)

Here is some of my code

app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "slim-select/dist/slimselect.min.css";
```

I tried removing the file extension from slim select, which fixed it.

But I am curious why and if there is some way to be able to import it the way I originally did but adjusting something else.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by removing the file extension, which loaded slimselect the same way bootstrap was being loaded.

This was just a random problem and I'm happy to share my solution, but also curious for any other information of why this worked.

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "slim-select/dist/slimselect";
```